# Y coordinate is out of range in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

I am working on constructing and saving a bitmap, and i have a loop that sets the pixels in the bitmap to their proper values. However it crashes after a short period of ime with an IndexOutOfRange exception at the noted point in the code.

```
    //data is an array of bytes of size (image width * image height) * 2;
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 2)
    {
        int luminance = ((int)data[i] << 8) | (int)data[i + 1];
        Color c = Color.FromArgb(luminance,luminance,luminance,luminance);

        int x = i / 2;
        int y = x / width;
        x %= width;
        b.SetPixel(x, y, c);//crashes here when Y is at 513, should only go to 512
    }
    b.Save(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + ".bmp");
```

I'm stumped as to why this happens.Why does this happen and how can i fix it?

(a note ot all of those that reommend unsafe code: I am going for a working program then a fast one. I'll be sure to write up 3 questions on the subject when i start! ;) )

Comment: Please add a line to print out data.Length, width and height just before you enter the loop, and then edit your question with those values. I suspect they're not what you expect them to be.

Comment: Note that the "i+1" is unnecessary, by the way - i will always be even, so adding one to it before dividing by two won't change the result.

Comment: Still setPixel? Please take a look at "unsafe code". For a faster code/program ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what might be wrong without knowing what your `data` actually is. I suspect that it might be organised into rows like a bitmap, but sometimes bitmap format data requires that rows be a multiple of 4 bytes in length (with unused padding at the end, see [BMP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)). If this is the case, your `y` value might become larger than you expect. You may need to take such padding into account.

Answer (score 1):

When Length is odd, then at some point i+1 == Length will be true.

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 2)
{
   int luminance = ((int)data[i] << 8) | (int)data[i + 1];

   int x = (i + 1) / 2;
}
```

I would suggest replacing

```
//data is an array of bytes of size (image width * image height) * 2;
```

with

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(data.Length == width * height * 2);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert((data.Length % 2) == 0);
```

Comment: The comment in the first line of the code indicates that `data.Length` will be even. However, you're right that this has not been confirmed.

Comment: It is even however testing indicates that the array's length is close to (but not quite) width * height * 8. It gets stranger and stranger...

Comment: Sounds like you may have 8 bytes / pixel + header.

Comment: Sounds reasonable but the file is actually just under width * height * 8. I'll do some more testing though...